# Equation of a reflected wave at a fixed end

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, reflection, boundary-conditions

If $y1=Asin(kx-wt)$, it is identical with $y2=-Asin(wt-kx)$.

But then if I write a reflected equation of y1, it is -Asin(kx+wt), whereas the reflected equation for y2 becomes Asin(wt+kx) since both the phase and direction of motion get changed at the fixed end.

But how can the same wave equations y1 and y2 end up in different reflections that are out of phase?

What's wrong with my logic here? I feel like I'm missing something very simple...but important.

Comment: Can we assume the point of reflection is located at x=0?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the wave in terms of the speed of sound $c$ and  $\kappa = \tfrac{\omega}{c}$ then

$$ y_{1}=A\sin\left(\omega\left(\tfrac{x}{c}-t\right)\right)=-A\sin\left(\omega\left(t-\tfrac{x}{c}\right)\right) $$

then the reflected wave is

$$y_{1}^{\star}=-A\sin\left(\omega\left(-\tfrac{x}{c}-t\right)\right)=A\sin\left(\omega\left(t+\tfrac{x}{c}\right)\right)$$

which is not the same. The reflected wave is found by switching the sign for the speed $c$ and the sign of the amplitude $A$.

Comment: I think the reflected wave should be Asin(wt+kx), the reflected wave has velocity in negative x direction, sign of kx term flips + phase of change of π

Comment: If the particle at x=0 is the point of reflection , then if it was earlier oscillating with -A sin(wt) for travelling wave, for reflected wave it will oscillate with A sin(wt), thus superposition of which , gets the net motion cancelled. Write the wave equation for both the waves, you'll notice the "kx" term flips sign

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: so the final reflected wave equation is Asin(wt+kx), right?

Comment: @PinkAura - yes